# Horizontal Alignment in LaTeX

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=14in,left=1cm,right=1.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry} %margins
\usepackage{amsmath,polyglossia,fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}
\parindent=0in % no spacing at the start of paragraphs
\begin{document}
Here is some text in arabic 
\\
\hfill
\textarabic{
اَللَّھُمَّ    إِنِّیْ
}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to start the Arabic from right to left but it seems \hfill is not working. So if there is another way to do this do tell me kindly.

Comment: Substitute `\hfill` with `\hspace*{\fill}`

Comment: as @karlkoeller the star form will in general not be ignored at the "start" of a line (also you should not have a space or linebreak before the `\\ `0 However something is wrong: you should not have to "fake" RTL typesetting by flushing to the right by hand, if that were marked as an arabic paragraph (rather than as a fragment of arabic text in an english paragraph it should start at the correct side automatically.

Comment: Did you try loading the `arabxetex` package?

Answer (score 2):

The `\text⟨lang⟩` macro is only for short insertions. Use `\begin{⟨lang⟩} … \end{⟨lang⟩}` instead. It will typeset a new paragraph. In your case when you use `Arabic` the paragraph is typeset right-to-left.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=14in,left=1cm,right=1.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry} %margins
\usepackage{amsmath,polyglossia,fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}
\parindent=0in % no spacing at the start of paragraphs
\begin{document}
Here is some text in arabic 

\begin{Arabic}
اَللَّھُمَّ    إِنِّیْ
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Note that you cannot use the environment `arabic`, as `\arabic` is
deﬁned internally by LaTeX. You need to use the environment `Arabic` instead.

Comment: Thanx, it really works :)